# Practices for Periodic Routines Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, database-design

I want to develop an application that creates todo list for users' periodic tasks list. I want users to allow to see their tasks that they performed/didn't perform and will perform. And users can see their tasks that performed at correct time or not. How can I design entities and relationships? Thanks,

**Update**:
[image]

Comment: This question is way too broad.   Break it into smaller tasks.

Comment: What have you designed so far? If you show what you have started, we gladly help out.

Comment: I updated my question.